# How to choose clusters from variable clustering (varclus) procedure?

Tags: r, regression, clustering

I am attempting some variable reduction before I perform a logistic regression.  I am quite interested in using `Hmisc::varclus` in R.  However, I am having some difficulty interpreting the output.  As far as I can tell, the (tree) plot produced using `varclus` is the only built-in way to get information on the groups created by the procedure.

My main question involves knowing at what level of the hierarchy to select the clusters to be used for variable reduction?  I read that of a rule-of-thumb to keep a cluster is if its rho (for Spearman's) is at least 0.30.  Would this be evaluated visually from the plot?  At what value of rho would the cut-off be made to separate the tree into *final* clusters? Again, is this to be done visually?

Perhaps my internet searching skills are lacking, but I am having difficulty finding information on this procedure in general and more specifically in R. Is there a good *beginner's* article on variable clustering that I am missing that spells out the fundamentals?  Are there additional commands for `varclus` in R to help with final cluster decisions besides examining the tree visually?

```
# varclust example in R using mtcars data
mtcn <- data.matrix(mtcars)
clust <- varclus(mtcn)
clust
plot(clust)
```

Comment: Make a search on this site and elsewhere of `clustering criterions`, `cluster validation`, `determine number of clusters` `clustering stopping rules`.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks for the search terms.  Are the procedures used with /for/on `hclust` able to be used with 'variable clustering?'   Provided that I can perform them specifically with `varclus` I still will need to produce output that is more than just the tree.

Comment: By leap: 1) I'm not R user, so don't know. 2) There is R package NBClust with many many clustering criterions. 3) You should read on this topic carefully to be able to choose among them. 4) You do clustering be any package you like, save a range of cluster solutions (membership variables) and then apply a clustering criterion from NBClust or such. 5) Yes, you may choose clusters simply by contemplating the dendrogram; this is simple, old and not very good way. Note that you can't compare dendrograms of different aglomerative methods in order to choose the 'best' method.

Comment: Why are you even using VARCLUS for variable selection? You'd be much better off using LASSO...

Comment: @MikeHunter with LASSO you need to consider the output variable (y) as well to select variables butfor VARCLUS you don't need the 'y', you only look at the independent variables (ie. 'x's) ?