# Evaluating clusters of variables produced by varclus & hclustvar

Tags: r, clustering, spss

Background - I want to cluster analyze a mixed dataset, clustering the variables on the basis of correlational similarity. SPSS gives me this option, but doesn't allow me to evaluate the clustering solutions by providing statistical measures of heterogeneity change (e.g. pseudo F statistic) or direct measures of heterogeneity (e.g. CCC).

As such, I'm learning R. I've managed to cluster my variables using both the varclus and hclustvar procedures, both of which generate nice dendrograms that I can interpret visually. However I'm struggling to get R to provide me with some actual numbers, such as the statistics mentioned above, which might indicate what constitutes the "best" clustering solution. How can I do this? I've been through the documentation for both the Hmisc and ClustOfVar packages and can't find any way to do this.

I've read [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49549/how-to-choose-clusters-from-variable-clustering-varclus-procedure) that clustering criteria can be applied using the NBClust package, but as far as I can see the NBClust function only works on dissimilarity matrices / distance measures, which aren't an option for me as I'm interested in correlational similarity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) That isn't true that _all_ internal clustering criteria need distances. Some of them are "omnivorous" in this respect. Maybe `NBClust` requests distances all the way just for the authors subjective feeling of consistency. 2) You could transform _r_ into a dissimilarity, especially in euclidean _d_. 3) You should read first about different criterions because they each has its own "habits" or bias. 4) A number of most useful of the criterions were programmed by me to compute them in SPSS (visit my page).

Comment: "Clustering based on **correlational** similarity" - which is very different from distance measures -  sounds as if it's Principal Components Analysis (PCA) you're really looking for. I believe Cluster Analysis is rarely used for clustering variables since PCA is thought to be the better approach for this.

Comment: Late to the game, but PCA doesn't do feature selection, unless you do something like partial sparse principal component regression. Variable clustering based on correlation does. It can de-correlate your predictor matrix while keeping your features in their original form, which is much better for interpretation.